# Sum different rows

Tags: worksheet-function

I used a pivot table on my data and I like to know if there is a formula or a way to see only one total for Aaron Donahue.  Same thing with Abhi Gupta's line items.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVLUN.png)

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?